# Does AntiForgeryToken requires session state?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, csrf

I don't use session, so I removed it together with all HTTP modules I don't need.

I sometimes get this error: `System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.`

Or this one: `System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.`

When I enable session, it works.

*So the question is: does the csrf stuff depend on session state?*

Comment: Are you sure that your shared-hosting vendor hosts your application on just one web server?

Comment: @lowleveldesign I'm not certain. But fairly convinced, as the hostname is always the same in my logs, as is the IP.

Comment: and what about domain on which csrf cookies are set? Are you using your unique subdomain? If not, your application might receive cookies from other .NET application running on the same root domain.

Comment: @lowleveldesign Yes cookies always sent from my app for my `www.` subdomain.

Comment: Keep in mind you can use antiforgery tokens on login pages to prevent login csrf attacks. In this case there is no session state because the user hasn't logged in yet. Read this for more info: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/antiforgery-tokens-behind-the-scenes-dcddda54db8a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET session is not required for anti-forgery tokens to work. The token is stored in a hidden form field and in a cookie, separate from a cookie session (you may find details [here](https://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/asp-net-anti-forgery-tokens-internals/)). Additionally, when anti-forgery token is invalid, an exception is thrown so it does not look like the problem you have is connected with anti-forgery tokens. Maybe record a Fiddler session, attach it to a new SO question and we should be able to better guide you.

Comment: The exception is always thrown when you experience "double-login" or it's a separate problem?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it answers the original question directly. But the problem remains, so I'll open a separate question as you recommended.